# updating event handling to new class with toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not a full-time jQuery nor Javascript dev so sorry if dumb question. I think I need something like the live function for a swapping of class's I do to handle which value is tied to a selector.

I basically have markup that looks like this:

for unenabling:

```
<span id="enable-1695" data-id="1695" class="unenable-item">unenable</span>
```

for enabling:

```
<span id="enable-1695" data-id="1695" class="enable-item">enable</span>
```

I'd like to use toggleClass to update to enable-item after unenable is clicked. Also, I need the selector to update the runtime to these new values. I think this used to happen via the live method. How would I achieve this. I am currently doing it manually but the Javascript runtime doesn't update the event handling correctly.

What javascript would I use to ensure that this worked correctly?

Any help is apprecciated.

thx

Comment: What do you mean by "update the runtime to these new values" ?

Comment: basically, after updating the classes via addClass / removeClass for enable-item / unenable-item, they are pointing to the old event handlers and need to update to new event handlers. I think this was handled by live but not sure how to now.

Comment: Not completely sure what you are looking for, but it sounds like you should take a look at on(). That should solve your issue http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: hmm.. so the selector is being changed but it the old event handler is being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, perhaps "disable" might be a better word-choice here, but we're not here to nitpick grammar...

I'll assume that when you click the 'unenable' link, it should change to be an 'enable' link:

```
$('.unenable-item').live('click', function () {
    $(this)
        .removeClass('unenable-item')
        .addClass('enable-item')
        .text('enable');
    doSomethingWith($(this).data('id'));
});
$('.enable-item').live('click', function () {
    // the inverse of the above
});
```

Here, I used the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) function which kinda-sorta is like `.on` or its deprecated alias `.bind`, except that it doesn't actually attach the event handler to the objects selected by the selector. Instead it attaches a handler to the document and whenever there is a click on anything, it checks the selector then to see if it matches. You could also use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for more-targetted matching. Better explanation of these things exist in the documentation (linked).